# cannot install pycurl in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, pycurl

i try many way to install pycurl in windows 7 32 bit:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

but i get error:

```
c:\users\soft\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_i
nternal\commands\install.py:199: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to
 the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting pycurl
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/b3/0f3979633b7890bab609
8d84c84467030b807a1e2b31f5d30103af5a71ca/pycurl-7.43.0.3.tar.gz (215kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 198kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\soft\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c0a5hpyg\pycurl\
```

i also downlaod curl from here:
https://curl.haxx.se/windows/
and put the path in :

```
pip install pycurl --install-option="--curl-dir=D:/curl-7.67.0-win32-mingw"
```

but it say it need libcurl.lib not libcurl.a
but the  file i download from
https://curl.haxx.se/windows/
contain libcurl.a and not  libcurl.lib
also try to install setup from here:
https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/
but i only get docs not the .py files
https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/
 i already have python 3.7 and i know it now work with pycurl,
i install python 3.6 but no thing change
 so please give a solution, Thanks for help.

Comment: You could install a precompiled version of pycurl from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl

Comment: i try it and Successfully installed ,thanks